# How to pause for 5 seconds before drawing the next thing on Android?

Tags: android, draw, wait

Say I want to draw a line, then wait five seconds, then draw another line. I have a method like this:

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.drawLine(w/2, 0, w/2, h-1, paint);
        // PAUSE FIVE SECONDS
        canvas.drawLine(0, h/2, w-1, h/2, paint);
    }
```

How do I pause?

Comment: i have asked a similar question, check it out.

Comment: so you should give the link to your question !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wait in onDraw method it's called in the UI thread and you'll block it. Use flags to handle which line will be drawn

```
boolean shouldDrawSecondLine = false;

public void setDrawSecondLine(boolean flag) {
    shouldDrawSecondLine = flag;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int w = canvas.getWidth();
    int h = canvas.getHeight();
    canvas.drawLine(w/2, 0, w/2, h-1, paint);
    if (shouldDrawSecondLine) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, h/2, w-1, h/2, paint);
    }
}
```

Than use it in your code like this

```
final View view;
// initialize the instance to your view
// when it's drawn the second line will not be drawn

// start async task to wait for 5 second that update the view
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        view.setDrawSecondLine(true);
        view.invalidate();
        // invalidate cause your view to be redrawn it should be called in the UI thread        
    }
};
task.execute((Void[])null);
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use a CountDownTimer like this :

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.drawLine(w/2, 0, w/2, h-1, paint);
        // PAUSE FIVE SECONDS
        new CountDownTimer(5000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long miliseconds){}

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
               //after 5 seconds draw the second line
               canvas.drawLine(0, h/2, w-1, h/2, paint);
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Regards,

Comment: This requires me to change h, w, and canvas to final variables. When I do that and run it, only the first line is drawn.

Comment: i think you have missed to start the countdowntimer :!!! try to  display a msg logcat in the onFinish() method , and see if it is executed or not

Answer (score 1):

Well... you could set a flag in (which would be in some other method) and within your `onDraw()` based on the value of this flag draw that line.

i.e. maybe something like (though I'm not sure why you would need a pause)

```
invalidate();
pause/sleep();
//set flag
invalidate();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Thread.sleep(5000)`, that should do it.

Comment: That seems to wait five seconds, and then draw both lines.

Comment: Probably will and in any case you should never delay in your onDraw(). Would make your app feel laggy.

Comment: @source.rar Where and how would I do this, then?

Comment: @DeeV, I thought it was meant that all the drawing is executed in a separate thread.

Comment: @TheBeatlemaniac All drawing is done on the UI thread, and AFAIK, putting in a delay like that won't draw anything.  The screen won't update until the onDraw function returns.