# Animate Canvas over time

Tags: android, android-canvas

Original Question:
I am trying to draw rectangles on the canvas one after the other. I would like to pause for a second before drawing each object. How would I implement this feature?

---

EDIT:
This is the code that I have working so far. Not sure if this is the best practice. Suggest a better way if you know one.

```
boolean stopAnimation = false;

int currentRectangle = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler(){
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
    invalidate();
    System.out.println("redraw"+currentRectangle);
    currentRectangle++;
        if(currentRectangle>2){
          stopAnimation = true;
        }
};
};

public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    final Rect currentRect = new Rect(a, 0, b, c);
    canvas.drawRect(currentRect, paint); //wait a lil bit
    canvas.drawRect(newRect, paint);
}

public void run() {
   while (!stopAnimation) {
         try {
             Thread.sleep(200);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
             handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would solve your answer:

[How to pause for 5 seconds before drawing the next thing on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665967/how-to-pause-for-5-seconds-before-drawing-the-next-thing-on-android)

If you need specifics please reply and I would be happy to help.

Comment: I checked out that post and gathered a few things together. What I got working so far can be seen in the EDIT I posted above. Let me know if you know of a better way.